# load model hdf5 with chaquopy in android studio

Tags: android, chaquopy

my friend has train 1 model hdf5, i want to load that model in android studio with chaquopy but failed despite trying many ways.
My code like that, include pickle and keras:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
from os.path import dirname, join
from keras.models import load_model

def predict(src):
    filename = join(dirname(__file__),"best_model.hdf5")
    pickle_in=open(filename,"rb")
    #model = pickle.load(pickle_in) load with pickle
    model = load_model(filename)    #load with keras
    samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(src, sr = 8000)
    #classes = ['app', 'gmail', 'image', 'mess', 'phone']
    #prob=model.predict(samples.reshape(1,8000,1))
    #index=np.argmax(prob[0])
    return len(samples)
```

With pickle, the error "invalid load key, 'H'" appears. With load_model of keras, the error "ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional" appears. I tried changing the version of keras and tensorflow but the error persists.
I use Python 3.9 and when i install tensorflow 2.6.0 it get error "error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.6.0 (from versions: 2.1.0)". How should I load this model.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chaquopy currently only provides TensorFlow version 2.1.0, so models created with newer versions may not be compatible. Try regenerating your model with a matching version of TensorFlow.

To be notified when Chaquopy updates its TensorFlow version, you can subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/374).